# Android. ListView with PullToRefresh & QuickReturn

Tags: android, listview, pull-to-refresh

I`m use ListView with PullToRefresh library.
https://github.com/chrisbanes/Android-PullToRefresh
And I have some problems with implementation of QuickReturn functional. Something like this library - https://github.com/LarsWerkman/QuickReturnListView 
Maybe someone already faced with a combination of two such different functional?

Comment: Why don't you try to get it working and come back if you have specific issues?

Comment: Maybe you can use a `SwipeRefreshLayout` along with this library https://github.com/lawloretienne/QuickReturn