# QuickReturn and pulltorefresh

Tags: android, pull-to-refresh

I'm trying to implement both [`pullToRefresh`](https://github.com/chrisbanes/Android-PullToRefresh) and [`quickreturn`](https://github.com/LarsWerkman/QuickReturnListView) in a footer. There is a similar question but without answer in [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22613429/android-listview-with-pulltorefresh-quickreturn/24363623#24363623)

The first problem I'm facing is that when I try to get the `listview` from the fragment doing:

```
mListView = (QuickReturnListView) getListView();
```

A cast exception is thrown:

```
com.handmark.pulltorefresh.library.PullToRefreshListView$InternalListViewSDK9 
cannot be cast to com.example.app.QuickReturnListView
```

I tried adding the methods in `QuickReturnListView` to `PullToRefreshListView` but that generates new exceptions, I think the problem is that both libraries are working with the `onscroll` listener.

Comment: Ever tried using the [SwiperefreshLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/SwipeRefreshLayout.html)? Just a suggestion. You can see how it is implemented [here](http://antonioleiva.com/swiperefreshlayout/)

Comment: Have you looked into using a `SwipeRefreshLayout` along with this library https://github.com/lawloretienne/QuickReturn ?